# wp-login.php is blank in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

hi i have blog on wordpress the front end is working fine but when i use to go on /wp-admin or /wp-login.php it shows me blank screen , my .htacess is as follow

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /blog/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

i have also tried by renaming the plugins folder and by removing the blank lines from the config file but affect it still shows me the blank page , but my blog is working fine

Comment: I would start with turning on error reporting, in index.php add ini_set('display_errors',1);  ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);  error_reporting(-1);

Comment: what will these lines do ?

Comment: it will display what's wrong with the code at your screen ;-)

Comment: it displays nothing the screen is still blank

Comment: check php error log. If you having wordpress 3.6 and working on php 5.4 or above it might u need some changes in wp_xx.php files.